# Help with high CPU on Oracle Rac node caused by Oracle processes with *_so and *_ag in the process command name

Tags: oracle, performance, linux

I have one node in a RAC cluster that is seeing very high CPU and it seems to be caused by several Oracle processes ending with _ag and _so in the process command name. The other node is not seeing any signs of trouble with CPU.
Can any of you Oracle experts help me get to the cause of these processes taking up more CPU than the database processes? I am guessing they are part of the diagnostics processes but not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those are just server processes belonging to user sessions in the database. `ag` and `so` are the first 2 characters in lowercase of the instance they belong to. They have nothing to do with diagnostics. Background processes are displayed in a different format.

You should focus on the java process with pid 5400 consuming over 300% CPU.

Comment: Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

I see that your answer is already answered, but I want to add this small hint anyway:

"top -c" will show the complete command, sometimes 15 digits are just not enough.

Comment: Thank you so much!